# generating uniform distribution of integeres with python

Tags: python, random, numbers, integer, uniform-distribution

I tried to generate an uniform distribution of random integeres on a given interval (it's unimportant whether it contains its upper limit or not) with python. I used the next snippet of code to do so and plot the result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint

propsedPython = np.random.randint(0,32767,8388602)%2048
propsedPythonNoMod = np.random.randint(0,2048,8388602)
propsedPythonNoModIntegers = np.random.random_integers(0,2048,8388602)
propsedPythonNoModRandInt = np.empty(8388602)
for i in range(8388602):
    propsedPythonNoModRandInt[i] = randint(0,2048)

plt.figure(figsize=[16,10])
plt.title(r'distribution $\rho_{prop}$ off all the python simulated proposed indices')
plt.xlabel(r'indices')
plt.ylabel(r'$\rho_{prop}$')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.hist(propsedPython,bins=1000,histtype='step',label=r'np.random.randint(0,32767,8388602)%2048')
plt.hist(propsedPythonNoMod,bins=1000,histtype='step',label=r'np.random.randint(0,2048,8388602')
plt.hist(propsedPythonNoModIntegers,bins=1000,histtype='step',label=r'np.random.random_integers(0,2048,8388602)')
plt.hist(propsedPythonNoModRandInt,bins=1000,histtype='step',label=r'for i in range(8388602):propsedPythonNoModRandInt[i] = randint(0,2048)')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

The resulting plot is:[image] Could somebody point me in the right direction why these spikes appear in al the different cases and or gives some advice which routine to use to got uniformly distributed random integers?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is using Numpy a requirement?

Comment: @Alex, Yes it does. I just edited my question with an "import section".

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the plot? I suspect the spikes are an artifact of the binning used. It's unlikely that they represent a deficiency in the underlying PRNG.

Comment: I agree with @MarkDickinson, but it's hard for us to confirm if you don't post a working example that illustrates the problem.  Trying to run what you posted produces `name 'proposedIndices' is not defined`.

Comment: I concur with @MarkDickinson and pjs, this is why I put in my answer manual binning. Just plug in your RNG and try to redraw your graphs

Comment: I just edited my question. So now one can it run without any problem. You were actually right, the problem was an artifact of the binning. BTW ```proposedIndices``` was just a large number so correcting for that error of mine would not have been too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm...

I used new NumPy rng facility, and graph looks ok to me.

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng()

N = 1024*500

hist = np.zeros(2048, dtype=np.int32)

q = rng.integers(0, 2048, dtype=np.int32, size=N, endpoint=False)

for k in range(0, N):
    hist[q[k]] += 1

x = np.arange(0, 2048, dtype=np.int32)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stem(x, hist, markerfmt=' ')
plt.show()
```

and graph

[image]